# "Flat chain complex"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Given a flat module $F$ and an exact sequence $A_\bullet$, a tensor product of chain complexes
$$F\otimes A_\bullet$$
is again exact, where $\otimes$ is defined as in [Tensor product of chain complexes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tensor+product+of+chain+complexes)
and $F$ regarded as a chain complex concentrated in degree $0$.

My question is, is it true that for any chain complex $F_\bullet$ whose components are all flat and an exact sequence $A_\bullet$, a tensor product of chain complexes
$$F_\bullet\otimes A_\bullet$$
is again exact?

Moreover, how about the inner-hom $[F_\bullet, A_\bullet]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no boundedness conditions on the complexes then this need not be true. For example, let $F_\bullet=A_\bullet$ be the unbounded complex
$$\cdots\xrightarrow{\times 2}\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\times 2}\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\times 2}\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\times 2}\cdots$$
of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$-modules (so it is both exact and a complex of flat $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$-modules).

Then each component of $F_\bullet\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}}A_\bullet$ is isomorphic to
$$\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z},$$
the kernel of the differential is
$$\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z},$$
and the image of the differential is
$$\left\{(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}\in\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}
\,\middle\vert\,\sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}a_i=0\right\}.$$
So $F_\bullet\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}}A_\bullet$ has homology isomorphic to $2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ in each degree, and in particular is not exact.

However, with suitable boundedness conditions, it is true.

If $F_\bullet$ is bounded, then an induction argument on the length of $F_\bullet$ shows that $F_\bullet\otimes A_\bullet$ is exact. From this one can prove that $F_\bullet\otimes A_\bullet$ is exact if

(a) either $F_\bullet$ or $A_\bullet$ is bounded, or

(b) both $F_\bullet$ and $A_\bullet$ are bounded above, or

(c) both $F_\bullet$ and $A_\bullet$ are bounded below.

[Alternatively, spectral sequence arguments can be used.]

Similar results hold for the internal Hom, but conditions (b) and (c) are replaced by the condition that one of $F_\bullet$ and $A_\bullet$ is bounded below, and the other is bounded above.